# Interpretation of "ならできるよう"

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I have the following sentence that a character says:

> その上で、
>   協力できる事があるならできるよう善処する。

Context: Characters fought and are about to join up. Also this character tends to not speak 100% proper default Japanese. They tend to eat the particles I think. So I'm thinking that a に could have been swallowed after に.

And I'm confused by the あるならできるよう bit.

協力できる事があるなら is simple "If we are able to have cooperation" / "If we are able to cooperate".

Also if the last bit is

> Something + できるよう善処する

That would mean something along the lines of "We'll do our best to be able + something". But how all this fits together is beyond me.

For now I think this means something along the lines of **"Moreover,
we should do our best if we are to be able to cooperate."** but I'm not so sure.

Basically the question is what is the actual meaning and how does this sentence split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「その上{うえ}で、協力{きょうりょく}できる事{こと}があるならできるよう善処{ぜんしょ}する。」

＝

> 「その上で、協力できる事があるなら、できるよう善処する。」

≒

> 「その上で、 協力できる事があるなら、（協力）できるよう（に）善処する。」

Above is how one should parse and understand this sentence even though I must say that the **first sentence is already quite normal**.  In Japanese, the use of punctuations is pretty much left to the writer's discretion.

「～～よう善処する」 is actually more formal than 「～～よう**に**善処する」.  The latter is more conversational.

The sentence means:

> "Moreover, if there is anything that we can cooperate with you on, we will do our best."

So, your overall comprehension was actually alright.

Comment: Well, my understanding is then actually false ;) since I thought she was saying that they should try to cooperate, as in not get on each other nerves so they can work together.
While in fact she is saying that if they can agree on cooperation, they should find something to cooperate on. Which actually makes more context sense.
The bit you enlightened me on is that the 協力 is subject of both fragments and where the split is. Thanks.
Marking as answer.