# Is there a difference between よう and ように?

Tags: grammar

> 必ずや主の望まれる結果となるよう、最善を尽くします！

It seems to work just like ように, but there must be a (subtle) difference between the two, right?

Comment: I think I have seen comments that よう is more commonly used than ように or something, but they mean pretty much the same. But I'm not sure, so I'm not giving it as an answer.

Comment: Ah yes. Here it is. This might be related to your problem: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54974/interpretation-of-%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%82%8b%e3%82%88%e3%81%86